# if else statement reverse

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

the result I want is second if else statement if code not in the list then alert, I don't get why the first if else statement fail, I thought that just reverse second if else statement ?? do I misunderstand some thing??

https://jsfiddle.net/e6qohvhc/

```js
var code = '500';

    if (code != '400' || code != '401' || code != '500') {
     console.log('true');  // I don't want it alert here
    }
    
    
    if (code == '400' || code == '401' || code == '500') { 
      // I have to always leave this empty line  ...
    } else {
    console.log('second true');
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, but boolean !(a||b) is !a&&!b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

If you want to invert a statement you have to invert every operator.

`!a` becomes `a`, `b` becomes `!b`, `||`becomes `&&`, `&&` becomes `||`.

So the inversion of your second `if` would be something like

```
(code != '400' && code != '401' && code != '500')
```

Answer (score 4):

You may need to review the [Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Basically, if you want to negate `(a || b || c)` you need to use `(!a && !b && !c)`

Hope it helps,

Comment: thanks for reply, so should I doing this `(code != '400' && code != '401' && code != '500')`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(code != '400' || code != '401' || code != '500'){}
```

always will be true because a variable cant be equal to multiple values

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `||`
First if statement for `500` is always true, that's why you are having problem/
Do it in this way and it should work the way you wanted it (check it out in your fiddle);

```
var code = 500;
alert(code);
console.log(code);
if (((code !== 400) || (code !== 401)) && (code !== 500)) {
    console.log('true');
  alert("123");
}

else if ((code == 400) || (code == 401) || (code == 500)) {
    alert("456");
} else {
console.log("second true");
alert("else");
}
```